# .Net UserControl - Docking 2 controls

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, docking

Let say I have 2 controls in a usercontrol :

One (controlA) that have a fixed height and need to be dock in the bottom and an other (controlB) in the top that must fill the leaving space.

If I use bottom dock for controlA and fill dock for controlB it's doesn't work because controlA goes over controlB ...

How can I do this correctly, I'm pretty new to the docking thing ...

I use .Net 3.5 c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the order in which you add the controls. Whichever order you're currently adding them in, reverse it :) Right-click on the covered up control and select "Bring to Front" in the designer.

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6165908.html) covers the problem in a bit more detail.